# bazaar pull special usage

Tags: bazaar

I have local folder that is branch from formal_versions.
My workflow is:

1. Mkae changes and than `commit` them
2. The integrator `merge` them in his local branch.
3. The integrator `push` its local branch to formal_versions
4. I use `pull` to make my local branch identical to formal_versions

This is working fine.
However what should I do in the following scenario:

1. After `pull` from formal_versions , I compile the code. As a result , some workspace and obj file are changed (I.E date and time of compilation) and of cource , bazaar explorer inform me on modified files
2. I again want to make my branch mirror of formal version. What should I do?

   A. Why using  `pull` again says that "nothing to pull" even if 
   I use --overwrite switch ? it is suppose to make my local branch as **mirror** of the pulled branch...

   B. Is my only option is to use revert working tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally considered best practice (as well as good for one's sanity) not to version files that are the result of the build process. Executables, shared libraries, and even source files generated from by a 4GL are examples. You can ignore files by using `bzr ignore <pattern>`, for example `bzr ignore *.exe`. If the files are already versioned, you will also have to remove them using `bzr remove`.

`bzr pull` says there is nothing to pull because the formal version has had no new commits since your last pull.

If you must version the files in question, `bzr revert` is the only way I know of when `bzr pull` does not find new revisions. If there had been new revisions in the formal branch, the files should be updated (and will potentially be reported as conflicts).

Comment: what do you mean by "bzr pull will not update your working tree, only the branch history (as shown by bzr log)." ? pull in my scenario , change my local files so they will be the same as the fomral_version branch.

Comment: and i know it not good practice but my team leader insists... i will try to convince him again

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about that. I'm used to working with checkouts, which behave a little differently in this scenario. I'm editing the answer to correct that.